# How can I troubleshoot the reason for my MongoDB server suddenly taking 100% CPU?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm about ready to go live with my node.js/mongo app running on the Amazon Cloud. I have a 3x replica set for the Mongo servers. Everything was working fine until, suddenly, about 20 minutes ago, the PRIMARY mongo server jumped to 100% CPU usage (usually it has barely any usage). I'm currently testing the app with only ~10 users, so this is very worrysome.

My first reaction was, of course, to grab the mongodb log file from the server. I expected this to be revealing, but now I'm more confused than ever. One of the primary functions of my database is to cache data for users, so I have a Collection ('DataCache') which simply stores a JSON string (Mongoose code):

```
new Model('DataCache',{ 
  '_id': { type: String, unique: true }, 
 'data': String, 
 'updated': Date });
```

Looking at the logs from the "100% CPU" time I see that the standard update requests were performed, but taking as much as ~47 seconds !!

```
Mon Aug  6 08:58:36 [conn28821] update storage.datacache query: { _id: "14954006/mentions/dcc3c69e72da714a0f3bffc518183ebb" } update: { $set: ... } } 47174ms
```

This request was not any longer in data than usual (about 1000 characters in the JSON string; data was truncated here for brevity).

I'm really not sure where else to be looking to figure out why my usage suddenly jumped so far up. I can't imagine what was unusual/unique about this scenario, and I don't see anything else in the logs, but I'm very worried about what will happen when our 10 users scale to thousands...

The problem disappeared as suddenly as it appeared, about 20 minutes after starting, but the CPU is still seeing weird spikes (RightScale dashboard image):
[image: RightScale]

---

UPDATE: Here's some info printed from mongo about the cache collection, in particular. I'm not certain that the problem has to do with the cache collection, but it is the one query I was seeing the most consistently during the lag-time...

```
     {
        "ns" : "storage.datacache",
        "count" : 43949,
        "size" : 132274592,
    "avgObjSize" : 3009.729277116658,
    "storageSize" : 158887936,
    "numExtents" : 13,
    "nindexes" : 5,
    "lastExtentSize" : 33828864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1.0099999999994833,
    "flags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 10972192,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 4570384,
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

---

EDIT: More graphs
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you let us know the instance size that you are running on AWS? Also, during this spike, did you look at the current operations running on the database? Were there any other activities happening on that instance at the time?

Comment: I'm using m1.small instances for all 3 replicas at the moment; I'm happy to upgrade, but if these are insufficient for 10 users I'm seriously concerned about scalability. Could you point me to how to look @ concurrent operations on the database? I wasn't seeing anything but these "update" requests in the mongodb log files, but I'm not sure if I should be looking at something else...

Comment: When you log into your instance ... you can run the following command: db.currentOp.inprog.length to get the number of operations at any given moment.

To see the actual operations ... just lop off the inprog.length, so: db.currentOp()

Comment: Also, during the spike, can you run an iostat -x 1 from the command line? That would give you a good idea of the IO occurring on the box. Finally, are you building any indexes during that time ... are they rebuilt with each code deploy?

Comment: Thanks for the commands; if/when the spike happens again I'll run those. I don't believe I'm building any indexes; I'm using Mongoose (node.js module), which should be pretty conservative and optimal with such tasks IIRC...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally with MongoDB a CPU spike comes from a couple of specific problems. Typically, MongoDB is very low CPU. It is normally entirely bound by IO or Memory footprint.

Here is (hopefully) a useful short list:

1. **Bad queries.** That's any query without an index. I notice that `DataCache` has an `Updated` field that is un-indexed. Do you every query by that field?
2. **Map / Reduce**. A Map / Reduce job will typically "peg" one core at 100%. How many cores do you have on these DBs? Are you running MR jobs?
3. **IO masking as CPU**. Depending on the reporting, CPU may actually be `CPU_WAIT`, which is often disk IO.

So if you go back to the graphs, take a look at your IO times and your RAM usage. Figure out your RAM:DATA ratio and figure out your IO needs. And let us know what type of machines you're using.

Comment: 1) I do not query by the updated field, no. That said... there are a number of other collections, as well. Is it bad practice to be a bit overzealous in my use of index:true? I'll go add these in a bit more freely in my models if not.
(2) I'm not doing any of these
(3) Hm, would this be reflected in disk usage graphs? How would I detect it? I've updated my original post with some more graphs...

Comment: MongoDBs are all m1.small instances. I've updated the original post with even more graphs. Please let me know if I can provide anything else.

Comment: @ZaneClaes, hi. I know this was a long time ago, but do you happen to remember what was your solution?